# PyCharm PRO for Mac GAE upload not working

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, pycharm

My colleague and I both have Macs, and we both have PyCharm Professional, same version (2016.3.2) and build (December 28, 2016). We use a repository to keep our project directories in sync, and they are currently identical. Under Preferences, we both have "Enable Google App Engine support" checked, and we both have the same directory shown as "SDK directory", with the same files in that directory.

When I choose menu option `Tools > Google App Engine > Upload App Engine app...`, the App Config Tool panel appears at the bottom of my PyCharm window. The first line is:

> /usr/bin/python
>   /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/appcfg.py
>   update .

and the last line is:

> appcfg.py >

I can also run that update command from a Terminal window.

Meanwhile, my colleague can also run the update command from a Terminal window. But when he runs menu option `Tools > Google App Engine > Upload App Engine app...`, the App Config Tool panel only shows:

> appcfg.py >

We've researched this extensively and made many attempts at repair, no luck so far. Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean install recently, and not using the AppEngineLauncher anymore - not sure it even ships with the newer SDK.

My GAE is located here:
/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine

Looks like you might be using an older version of AppEngine SDK